# SQL Server LIKE caret (^) for NOT does not work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I was reading the article at [mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9115/excluding-characters-with-regular-expressions-with-t-sql/) and wanted to try the caret in regex. I understand regex pretty well and use it often, although not much in SQl Server queries.

For the following list of names, I had thought that  `1) select * from people where name like '%[^m]%;'` will return those names that do not contain 'm'. But it doesn't work like that. I know I can do `2) select * from people where name not like '%m%';` to get the result I want, but I'm just baffled why 1) doesn't work as expected.

1. Amy
2. Jasper
3. Jim
4. Kathleen
5. Marco
6. Mike
7. Mitchell

I am using SQL Server 2017, but here is a fiddle:

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05388/5)

Comment: SQL Server has no built in regex support, that article is misleading.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-not-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) hopefully clarifies the expected behaviour.

Comment: I would love to see SQL Server handle regex!! Maybe someday, but I don't think we'll get that in our lifetime. It does some absolutely remarkable things, but SQL Server is not great at handling text processing of any kind. I mean, basic things, yeah, it's covered, but not complex things. We have 'like' and 'not like'....and that's pretty much it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'%[^m]%'` would be true for any string containing a character that is not `m`. An expanded version would be `'%[Any character not m]%'`. Since all of those strings contain a character other than `m`, they are valid results.

If you had a string like `mmm`, `where name like '%[^m]%'` would not return that row.

Comment: You got it. Thank you. I haven't thought about that.  So I guess query 2) in my original post is the only way to achieve the expected result.